# Multiple values for a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

My site allows the user to attach multiple tags to their post (much like StackOverflow).

Is it better to store the tags in a single column, i.e.:

**posts table**

```
+---------+--------------------+
| post_id |        tags        |
+---------+--------------------+
|       1 | first,second,third |
|       2 | first              |
|       3 | first,third        |
+---------+--------------------+
```

Or is it better to create a separate table to hold the tags separately, i.e.:

**post_tags table**

```
+---------+--------+
| post_id |  tag   |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | first  |
|       1 | second |
|       1 | third  |
|       2 | first  |
|       3 | first  |
|       3 | third  |
+---------+--------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Neither, make a third table for `Tags` and add all of the tags there, and make a bridge table that has just the `post_id` and `tag_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference, at least that's the way I see it.

Let's say you choose option **post_table**

You want to present the number of post for a given tag in a webpage. To do that you'll need to do a query using LIKE (or MATCH AGAINST if the tags column has a FULLTEXT index which is better). For example:

```
SELECT count(post_id) FROM post_table WHERE tags LIKE '%first%';
```

Will give you the number of post that have the "first" tag. (**thanks to a comment I realized that if various tags have the "first" word in it, then it will give you an incorrect count of posts with the tag "first"**)

If you choose the option **post_tags**

You'll need a simple query like this:

```
SELECT count(post_id) FROM post_tags WHERE tag = 'first';
```

Since the first option could cause incorrect results to be retrieved from the tables, the second would be the only option to choose.

**P.D.** You can also create a separate "tag_table" to hold the tags with a numeric ID for each one, and also an union table "post_rel_tags" to hold the ID of the post and the ID of the tag. This way you save space in the database because you're dealing just with numeric values to make the relationships, but queries won't be so simple (actually they're simple, but with the options you proposed, they're even more simpler)

Comment: It will matter to your database admin and developers.  %first% would match anything with first in it.  So what about a tag that is called first-place or headfirst?  The second method (post_tags) is the valid method.

Comment: You're right, I didn't take that into account! It seems like option 2 is better to do queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be rephrased as follows: Is it better to adhere to first normal form (1NF) or not?

When a table in 1NF is queried, a single value can always be obtained by a keyed search.  Keyed searches use indexes when they are available and relevant.  This is why 1NF was devised.

If you never have to search for tags, then suit yourself.  But why would you use a database in that case?